# Can I inject a dependency into a model object created in a post method with .Net Core WebApi?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

If in my Startup I have registered my dependency:

```
services.AddScoped<IService, SomeService>();
```

Is there a way for this to be injected into my model object at instantiation via a post method?

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] Model myModel) { ... }
```

And my model class looks something like this.

```
public class Model {
...
    public Model(IService service) { ... }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to inject something into the model you can go with [custom model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-model-binder-sample). Inside ModelBinder you get access to context with all your registered services and you can call your model's constructor with any arguments that you need.

In general models should not keep reference to services that are using them. So please think it through, if you really want to go this way.

Comment: In a domain driven design shouldn't the models use the services and not the other way round? Models that have state but no behaviour would be considered anemic, so after the model is deserialised from JSON the next step would be to invoke behaviour on the model, which may require the use of a service to complete its operation. This dependency could be injected into the method on the model, but it would seem cleaner to me if this was done at instantiation of the model.

Why would you not want to hold references to the services in the model?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-model-binder-sample) for this purpose. We can use `ComplexTypeModelBinder` as base for this

```
public class ServiceModelBinder : ComplexTypeModelBinder
{
    public ServiceModelBinder(IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> propertyBinders, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
        : base(propertyBinders, loggerFactory)
    {
    }

    public ServiceModelBinder(IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> propertyBinders, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, bool allowValidatingTopLevelNodes) : base(propertyBinders, loggerFactory, allowValidatingTopLevelNodes)
    {
    }

    protected override object CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelTypeInfo = bindingContext.ModelType.GetTypeInfo();

        //if type satisfies default binder requirements just use it
        if (!modelTypeInfo.IsAbstract && modelTypeInfo.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
        {
            return base.CreateModel(bindingContext);
        }

        var constructors = modelTypeInfo.GetConstructors();
        if (constructors.Length > 1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Model should contain one constructor only");
        }

        var constructor = constructors.First();
        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
        //require that all parameters are marked with [FromServices]
        //this step is completely optional
        if (!parameters.Any(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(FromServicesAttribute))))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Mark all parameters with [FromServices]");
        }

        //build arguments from registered services
        var arguments = parameters
            .Select(p => bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(p.ParameterType))
            .ToArray();

        return constructor.Invoke(arguments);
    }

}
```

Then add a model binder provider (copied from ASP.NET Core sources)

```
public class ServiceModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType && !context.Metadata.IsCollectionType)
        {
            var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();
            for (var i = 0; i < context.Metadata.Properties.Count; i++)
            {
                var property = context.Metadata.Properties[i];
                propertyBinders.Add(property, context.CreateBinder(property));
            }

            var loggerFactory = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            return new ServiceModelBinder(
                propertyBinders,
                loggerFactory,
                allowValidatingTopLevelNodes: true);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And register it in startup

```
services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ServiceModelBinderProvider());
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

My ready solution using a custom model binder (does not require registering models in services):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Constructor)]
public class UseDIBinderAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class DIModelBinderProvider(IModelBinderProvider providerDefault) : IModelBinderProvider
{
   private class DIModelBinder(IModelBinder binderDefault) : IModelBinder
   {
      Task IModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
      {
         var modelTypeInfo = bindingContext.ModelType.GetTypeInfo();
         var constructors = modelTypeInfo.GetConstructors()
            .Where(static ci => ci.GetCustomAttribute<UseDIBinderAttribute>() != null).ToList();
         if (constructors.Count > 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Model should contain only one constructor with {nameof(UseDIBinderAttribute)}");

        var constructor = constructors.First();
        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
        var requestServices = bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;

        bindingContext.Model = constructor.Invoke(
           parameters.Select(p => requestServices.GetService(p.ParameterType)).ToArray());

        return binderDefault.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
     }
  }

  IModelBinder? IModelBinderProvider.GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
  {
     if (context.Metadata.ModelType.GetConstructors()
        .All(static ci => ci.GetCustomAttribute<UseDIBinderAttribute>() == null)) return null;

     return new DIModelBinder(providerDefault.GetBinder(context)
        ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Provider {providerDefault.GetType()} did not provide an IModelBinder for {context.Metadata.ModelType.Name}"));
  }
}
```

Register it in startup:

```
mvcBuilder.AddMvcOptions(static o =>
{
    var providerDefault = o.ModelBinderProviders.First(static p => p is ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider);
    var providerDI = new DIModelBinderProvider(providerDefault);
    o.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, providerDI);
}
```

Using:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
   [UseDIBinder]
   public SomeViewModel(ISomeService service)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**